# proving inequality (using triangle inequality)

Tags: calculus

Hi I need to prove the following inequality:

$|\sqrt(|a| + 1) - \sqrt(|b| + 1)| <= |a - b|$

It is known that:
$\sqrt x - \sqrt y = (x - y) / (\sqrt x + \sqrt y) $
It is also known (by triangle inequality) that: $|a - b| <= |a| - |b|$

Now it looks rather simple but I got stuck after using the first formula since i couldnt lose the denominator after it

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sqrt{|a| +1} + \sqrt{|b| + 1} \geq 1 + 1 = 2$,

hence

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{|a| +1} + \sqrt{|b| + 1}} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

See what to do now?

Comment: Oh cool didnt think about it but: so it is: (|a| - |b|)/(the thing you said) <= (|a| - |b|) / 2  which imo is closer to what i want but still how do i say that it is <= |a| - |b| without the / 2

Comment: Well, 1/2 < 1, yes?

Comment: lol i feel ashamed now.. i always overlook the simplest things thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{|a|+1}-\sqrt{|b|+1}\right|=& \left|\frac{|a|-|b|}{\sqrt{|a|+1}+\sqrt{|b|+1}}\right|\\
&<\left|\frac{|a|-|b|}{\sqrt1+\sqrt1}\right|\\&<|a-b|
\end{align}
$$